# Merge an array with a string variable in PHP implode

Tags: php, arrays, variables, concatenation, implode

```
implode(',', $a);
```

I want to attach the `$q` variable in front of the `$a` so like this

```
implode(',', $q.$a);
```

But that doesn`t work. How can i put 2 variables in a implode function?

`$a` is an array with domain names like "com, org" and `$q` is the text (string) you type in before the domain names will appear.

I get the following error:

> invalid argument passed in line..

Whole code:

```
$a = ['nl','net','com','co'];
$q = $_REQUEST["q"];

$domain = explode(".", $q);
$ext = @$domain[1] ?: ' ';


if (empty($ext)) {
    echo implode(',',$a);
} else if (in_array($ext, $a)) {
    echo $q;
} else {
    $r = [];
    foreach ($a as $x) {
        if (strstr($x, $ext)) {
            $r[] = $x;
        }
    }
    echo (count($r)) ? implode(',',$r) : implode(',',$a);
}
```

Comment: What are `$a` and `$q` ? And what error do you get?

Comment: $a is an array with domain names like "com, org" and $q is the text you type in before the domain names wil appear. And the error is "invalid argument passed in line.."

Comment: Can you Put $a , $q values and your expected result?

Comment: So `$a` is an array and `$q` is an other array?

Comment: How am I suppose to know what `$_REQUEST["q"]` is? Is it an array? Is it a string? What is the desired output because it's not clear? Please explain what you get (value of `$a` and `$q`) and what is the output you want.

Comment: @KoenM so `$q` is a string and `$a` is an array? if so check my answer

Comment: for example i type in "robot.c" what it shows now is "com, co" because the code is " ',',$a " and $q is like the text before that so "robot" and it checks once I put a dot the variables of $a will appear. But what I want is once I put robot.c I want this "robot.com, robot.co".

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want, but perhaps `array_map` or `array_reduce` or `array_walk` might be what you're looking for rather than `implode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$a` is an array and `$q` is the prefix string you can achieve that with 2 steps:

Add the prefix with:

```
$a = array("com", "co");
$q = "robot.";
foreach ($a as &$value)
    $value = $q.$value;
```

Second, use the implode:

```
echo implode(',',$a);
```

output is:

```
robot.com,robot.co
```

**Edited**

I think this will be more suitable for you:

```
$a = array("com", "co", "org");
$q = "robot.c";
$arr =  explode(".", $q);

$output = array();
foreach ($a as &$value) {
    if (substr($value, 0, strlen($arr[1])) === $arr[1])
        $output[]= $arr[0] . "." . $value;
}
echo implode(',',$output);
```

In this code you take the domain prefix and search for all domain name that may be fit for the prefix.

Notice that is this example we have domain `org` but he does not show up because your prefix is `c`

Comment: This is almost what I want, what I get now if I type in robot.c. "robot.ccom, robot.cco" etc.

Comment: @KoenM I guess you can add this `$q = substr($q, 0, strpos($q, ".") + 1);`

Comment: Can you check out my whole code I edited it in and tell me which things I have to change. Because you are the one that knows what I want to have.

Comment: @KoenM edited my answer - I think now it will answer you

Comment: Thanks man. sorry but I am a beginner, how do I make it so it won`t show robot.c anymore I used $q = $_REQUEST["q"]; but it says undefind offset line 9 @David Winder

Comment: What do you mean by `not show robot.c` anymore? is it element in the `$_REQUEST` array?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your `$q` before `implode` function. You can add your `$q` into your `$a` array using `array_map` function.

```
$array = array('com', 'org', 'net');
$q = 'test';
$array = array_map(function($value) { 
                    $q= "test"; // you $q value goes here.
                    return $q.".".$value; 
         }, $array);

echo implode(',',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Merge an array with a string variable in PHP with the help of implode function

```
$a = array("com", "co");
$q = "robot.c";
$temp = explode(".",$q);
foreach ($a as $value)
    echo $value = $temp[0].".".$value;
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stack Overflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your business logic guarantees that `$a` is never empty, then here is the most direct, efficient, and concise technique...

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2cdEk))

```
$a = ['nl', 'net', 'com', 'co'];
$q = 'example';

echo "$q." . implode(",$q.", $a);
```

Output:

```
example.nl,example.net,example.com,example.co
```

**See how there is no need to loop or call any additional functions?**

This basic technique of expanding the delimiting glue can be seen in other usages like:

```
echo '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>', $array) . '</td></tr>';
```

The idea is that you prepend what you need before the first value, then you declare the glue to be the characters that you need to occur after each value AND before the next value.